# Index error with Milvus 2.0.0, sdk: pymilvus 2.0.0

Tags: database, vector, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to create IVF_SQ8 index, but I encountered an error. Milvus 2.0.0, sdk: pymilvus 2.0.0

```
default_index = {"index_type": "IVF_SQ8", "metric_type": METRIC_TYPE, "params": {"nlist": 16384}}
status = self.collection.create_index(field_name="embedding", index_params=default_index)
```

Error: [image]

Answer (score 0):

From your error log "status = StatusCode.UNIMPLEMMENTED", I speculate that the sdk version of your milvus may not match your milvus server version. It is recommended to confirm it carefully.